# BrowserSync not trigger when watching .html files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch

I am using Gulp to compile and minify my SASS. This works fine, but I want to extend the automation by using BrowserSync.

I've followed the instructions on a few tutorial sites but cannot get it working - the browser does not refresh when I update either my .scss or .html files, not do any errors appear on the Terminal.

My gulpfile.js is as such. Would anyone know why browserSync fails to run?

(ps running `gulp browserSync` does sucessfully open the browser window and index file with `http://localhost:3000/` but there is no automatic refreshing).

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

// Normal .scss compilation
gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return gulp.src('scss/main.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
});

// Minifys .css, is meant to reload browser
gulp.task('mini-css', function() {
    return gulp.src('dist/css/main.css')
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }));
});

// Do both of the above
gulp.task('do-sass', gulp.series('sass', 'mini-css'))

gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series('do-sass'));
  gulp.watch("*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: './'
    },
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your watch task should be your default task. Try to put the browserSync.init() in the watch task und then start your gulp with **`gulp watch`**

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

// Normal .scss compilation
gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return gulp.src('scss/main.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
});

// Minifys .css, is meant to reload browser
gulp.task('mini-css', function() {
    return gulp.src('dist/css/main.css')
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }));
});

// Do both of the above
gulp.task('do-sass', gulp.series('sass', 'mini-css'))

gulp.task('watch', function(){
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: './'
    }
  });

  gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series('do-sass'));
  gulp.watch("*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```